# Dynamic array of structs inside of struct (in kernel module)

Tags: c, struct, kernel-module, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to assemble a certain structure for information that will be passed on to a function. This function takes the address and size as arguments. In addition the structure of the information is given by technical documentation but contains a dynamic part. The dynamic part consists of a structure which is repeated.
So it comes to mind to use an array of structs within a struct.

A minimal example could look like this:

```
struct nodeConfig_s{
  int pdoCount;
  int somethingElse;
  struct pdo_s{
    int flags;
    int dataLength;
    int id;
  } pdos[];
}
```

I do understand that `pdos[]` is just a pointer to the first element of the array.
But what I want to achieve is that the array of structs will be placed within the same memory area as the outer struct would be.

Is there a way to achieve that? It should be noted that I am depending on functions that are available in a GNU/Linux kernel module (2.6.37.6)

---

If there is a way to manage the information in a linked list (which is easily expendable) and putting it all together in one memory block (serializing?) later I would appreciate any help for that.

---

From the documentation I know that the maximum size of `pdos[]` is 255 but I really would like to avoid defining an array of that size and wasting all that memory.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a pointer to your structure

```
 struct pdo_s *pdos;
```

and allocate memory dynamically

```
pdos = malloc(sizeof(struct pdo_s));
```

By this way you allocate required memory and keep increasing the memory by doing a `realloc()` on the same pointer.

or

you can allocate 255 structs at once on heap or stack.

```
pdos = malloc(sizeof(struct pdo_s) * 255);
```

or

```
struct pdo_s pdos[255];
```

Comment: Unfortunately `realloc()` is not available in kernel space.

Comment: `malloc()` is available and `realloc()` not? Strange !! Then I think you need to allocate memory at the being i.e. 255 structs

Comment: More precisely: In a kernel module you can use: `kmalloc()`, `kcalloc()`, `vmalloc()`